# Abstraction/typing error resulting from case_eq and rewriting in Coq

Tags: coq

Consider the situation described by the code below, wherein I have a "piecewise" function `h` behaving differently (like `f`, or like `g`) depending on some (decidable) property `condition` of its input (`h` is defined using `case_eq`). Assume that I can prove that a `property` is guaranteed of the image of any `x` after application of either of the partial functions `f` or `g`; I should be able to prove that the entire function `h` guarantees `property` using a simple `case_eq` proof, no? Yet the following code rejects the `rewrite` step:

```
Section Error.

Variables X Y : Type.
Variables n m : Y.
Variable condition : X -> bool.
Variable property : Y -> Prop.

Definition type1 (x : X) : Prop := condition x = true.
Definition type2 (x : X) : Prop := condition x = false.

Variable f : {x:X | type1 x} -> Y.
Variable g : {x:X | type2 x} -> Y.

Definition h : X -> Y. intro x. case_eq (condition x); intro.
  - exact (f (exist type1 x H)).
  - exact (g (exist type2 x H)).
Defined.

Hypothesis Hf : forall x, property (f x).
Hypothesis Hg : forall x, property (g x).

Theorem hRange : forall x, property (h x).
Proof. intro. case_eq (condition x); intro.
  - unfold h. rewrite H.
```

with the error

```
Abstracting over the term "condition x" leads to a term
fun b : bool =>
property
  ((if b as b0 return (b = b0 -> Y)
    then fun H0 : b = true => f (exist type1 x H0)
    else fun H0 : b = false => g (exist type2 x H0)) eq_refl)
which is ill-typed.
Reason is: Illegal application: 
The term "exist" of type "forall (A : Type) (P : A -> Prop) (x : A), P x -> {x : A | P x}"
cannot be applied to the terms
 "X" : "Type"
 "type1" : "X -> Prop"
 "x" : "X"
 "H0" : "b = true"
The 4th term has type "b = true" which should be coercible to "type1 x".
```

Of course, I wish it would eliminate the `if` clause, rewriting the goal to `property (f (exist type1 x H))` but Coq doesn't like this. Why not?

---

I feel Coq wouldn't behave like this if the hypothesis generated by `case_eq` in the definition of `h` wasn't implicated in the result (in this case, I could've rewritten `h` with a `match` clause, and those cause me no issue. In the present situation, just assume that the hypothesis is crucial to constructing some "non-computational" part of either `f x` or `g x`, e.g. if `Y` is itself a sig-type). I've read other threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028580/abstracting-over-the-term-leads-to-a-term-which-is-ill-typed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867685/abstracting-leads-to-a-term-ill-typed-yet-well-typed), but to the short extent that I understand them, they don't help me understand my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occurs when you try to destruct or rewrite all the occurrences of a subterm.  Here, you've rewritten  `condition x` in the type of `H0`, which causes `exist type1 x H0` to be ill-typed (can you see why?).

The solution is to restrict the destruct or rewrite to only some of the subterms. This might require you to generalize part of your goal. For example:

```
From Coq Require Import ssreflect.

Section Error.

Variables X Y : Type.
Variables n m : Y.
Variable condition : X -> bool.
Variable property : Y -> Prop.

Definition type1 (x : X) : Prop := condition x = true.
Definition type2 (x : X) : Prop := condition x = false.

Variable f : {x:X | type1 x} -> Y.
Variable g : {x:X | type2 x} -> Y.

Definition h : X -> Y. intro x. case_eq (condition x); intro.
  - exact (f (exist type1 x H)).
  - exact (g (exist type2 x H)).
Defined.

Hypothesis Hf : forall x, property (f x).
Hypothesis Hg : forall x, property (g x).

Theorem hRange : forall x, property (h x).
Proof.
intro; unfold h; generalize (eq_refl (condition x)).
case: {2 3}(condition x).
- intros H. apply Hf.
- intros H. apply Hg.
Qed.

End Error.
```

After generalizing `eq_refl`, the goal looks like this:

```
1 subgoal (ID 16)


  X, Y : Type
  n, m : Y
  condition : X -> bool
  property : Y -> Prop
  f : {x : X | type1 x} -> Y
  g : {x : X | type2 x} -> Y
  Hf : forall x : {x : X | type1 x}, property (f x)
  Hg : forall x : {x : X | type2 x}, property (g x)
  x : X
  ============================
  forall e : condition x = condition x,
  property
    ((if condition x as b return (condition x = b -> Y)
      then fun H : condition x = true => f (exist type1 x H)
      else fun H : condition x = false => g (exist type2 x H)) e)
```

The tactic `case: {2 3}...`, which was imported from `ssreflect`, says that `condition x` should only be destructed on the RHS of `e` and on the condition of the `if`.

Comment: Interesting. If I understand, the 4th rewriting causes `H0 : condition x = true` to instead become a useless `H0: true = true`? Alas, I'm curious if the behavior of `rewrite` should (or even can) be tweaked one day to give a more helpful result in these circumstances. At any rate, in the case that I already have the hypothesis I want to rewrite into an `if` clause like this, is there any way to use SSreflect's rewrite to do that, rather than doing the case method here and then discriminating one of the branches?